# How to exclude records based on values in 2 other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server I need to select rows that have a specific value in one column, but I have to then take those records and exclude them from my results if they have specific values in 2 other tables. The records I want might not exist in the other 2 tables.

```
SELECT Table1.ID 
FROM 
Table1 
WHERE 
Table1.Column1 = 'A'
AND
Table1.ID NOT IN (SELECT Table2.ID FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Column2 = 'X')
AND
Table1.ID NOT IN (SELECT Table3.ID FROM Table3 WHERE Table3.Column3 = 'Y')
```

I keep getting records where ID does appear in Table2 but not Table3 and vice versa. What I want to do is exclude that ID if it's in either Table2 with Column2 = 'X' or Table3 with Column3 = 'Y'

I think my logic or syntax is wrong.

Plus I know "NOT IN" can do weird things if the results of a subquery contains NULLs, so I'm not sure if there's a more straightforward way to do this.

I've been rewriting this a bunch of different ways, but I'm not getting the results I want. I keep getting no records, too few records, or too many records...argh!

Any suggestions?

Comment: You `AND` condition only restrict IDs that exist in both Table2 and Table3.  Use `OR` instead for IDs that exist in either tables.

Comment: Read the question "in either ... or".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change to `OR`:

```
SELECT Table1.ID 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Table1.Column1 = 'A'
AND (
Table1.ID NOT IN (SELECT Table2.ID FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Column2 = 'X')
OR 
Table1.ID NOT IN (SELECT Table3.ID FROM Table3 WHERE Table3.Column3 = 'Y'))
```

or you could rewrite it to:

```
SELECT Table1.ID 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Table1.Column1 = 'A'
EXCEPT (
  SELECT Table2.ID FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Column2 = 'X' 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Table3.ID FROM Table3 WHERE Table3.Column3 = 'Y'
)
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.ID 
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2
  ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
 AND Table2.Column2 = 'X'
LEFT JOIN Table3
  ON Table1.ID = Table3.ID
 AND Table3.Column3 = 'Y'
WHERE Table1.Column1 = 'A'
  AND (Table2.ID IS NULL AND Table3.ID IS NULL);
```

Comment: What about using a left join? and in where clause saying where table2.id is null or table3.id is null

Comment: @Markov This is another possibility, feel free to post your own answer :)

Comment: But is except more efficient than left join with is null?

Comment: @Markov It depends on execution plan. Nowadays query optimizer is pretty smart.

Comment: well, I'll never know, I'm sitting on 2005 :( and I don't think an upgrade is happening anytime soon.

Comment: @Markov Wow, 2005 is really old :/ I hope you will get 2017 :)

Comment: I hope so too, Anyway, good answer, Feel free to add left join option to your answer :)

Comment: Hadn't thought of EXCEPT, I'll try that....unless someone thinks of something better!  :)

Comment: Not reason to UNION the EXCEPT.  Just call two EXCEPT.